# Subset data records that have dates within 4 years of each other?

Tags: r

I want to keep rows that are within 4 years of any other record within a site.
For example, here is a table with a Site field and a Date field with the records I want to remove highlighted.

I've been experimenting with rolling joins, but I'm having difficulty with the moving window of the sites.

```
    ex_dates<-read.csv(text=getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sregalado/Reg1/master/ex_dates.csv"), header=T)
    #Data
    ex_dates
    #   ID   SITE      Date
    #1   1 500001  9/4/2008 ###REMOVE
    #2   2 500001  9/5/2013
    #3   3 500001  9/6/2013
    #4   4 500001  9/7/2014
    #5   5 500001  9/4/2014
    #6   6 500001  9/5/2015
    #7   7 500001  9/6/2017
    #8   8 500001  9/7/2017
    #9   9 500002  9/4/2005 ###REMOVE
    #10 10 500002  9/6/2012
    #11 11 500002  9/7/2014
    #12 12 500002  9/4/2014
    #13 13 500002  9/5/2015
    #14 14 500003  9/5/2012
    #15 15 500003  9/6/2012
    #16 16 500003  9/7/2012
    #17 17 500003  9/8/2012
    #18 18 500003  9/9/2012
    #19 19 500003 9/10/2012
    #20 20 500003  9/7/2014
    #21 21 500003  9/4/2014
    #22 22 500003  9/5/2015
```

Comment: @John Coleman   The key to my criteria is that I want to keep records that are within 4 years of dates WITHIN a site. Although the highlighted sites are within 4 years of each other, they are within different groups.

Comment: Did my solution answer your question?

Comment: @JMT2080AD yes, your code worked nicely. Putting my thoughts into an R function was the hurdle. Thanks for helping me jump it!

Comment: The function isn't necessary, but I think it compartmentalizes the process nicely. You could just put the `sapply` in the data.table operation, but I think that might make it too cluttered. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution leverages some `data.table`. The goal here is group by `SITE` and then among those in the group check the difference for each date against all other dates in the group. If all other dates exceed a `yearDiff` threshold then mark the record as `TRUE`. You can then subset on that field.

```
library(data.table)

exDates <- fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sregalado/Reg1/master/ex_dates.csv")
exDates[,Date:=as.Date(Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")]

findRemoveByYearDiff <- function(dates, yearDiff){
    sapply(seq(length(dates)), function(x) all(abs(dates[x] - dates[-x]) > (365.25 * yearDiff)))
}

exDates[,rmRecord:=findRemoveByYearDiff(Date, 4), by = SITE]

exDates <- exDates[rmRecord != TRUE,]
```